# Code error with inserting image to range using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a excel template where users can select a range of cells and click on a button which prompt the user to select an image file.
Once image file is selected the image should be resized to selected range.

Below is my current code:

```
    Sub InsertImagetoRange()
    Dim ImageFile As Variant
    Dim ImageObject As Picture

    Dim myRange As Range
    With Application
    Set myRange = .Selection
    End With

    ImageFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Picture To Be Imported")
    If ImageFile = False Then Exit Sub
        Set ImageObject = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ImageFile)
        With ImageObject
           .Left = ActiveSheet.Range(myRange).Left
           .Top = ActiveSheet.Range(myRange).Top
           .Width = ActiveSheet.Range(myRange).Width
           .Height = ActiveSheet.Range(myRange).Height
           .Placement = 1
           .PrintObject = True
        End With
    End Sub
```

Currently above code insert an image to the right location, but gives and error immediately afterwords.

[image]

The image does not resize to the selected range, I have used the watch window to look at the range and `myRange` variable seems to be nothing at all times.

Any help pointing me to the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Stop` and <kbd>F8</kbd>, you can quickly work out that the error is on this line:

```
.Left = ActiveSheet.Range(myRange).Left
```

The reason for this is that `ActiveSheet.Range(myRange)` is invalid - [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) accepts either **two** `Range` objects, *or* **one** text address, in A1 format.  As `myRange` is a `Range` object, you are providing it with neither.

However, since `myRange` **is** a `Range` object, you can just do this instead:

```
.Left = myRange.Left
```

(Don't forget to do the same for `Top`, `Width`, and `Height` too!)

(Of couse, if cell `myRange` contains text that is a cell reference, such as cell A1 containing the text "B3", then the code won't error - *but*, it will put the image in the wrong cell, B3 instead of A1)

As for your other issue:  `myRange` will be stuck as `Nothing` if nothing is selected. If `Selection` is not a `Range` - for example, if you have an image selected - then you will get a different error (Type Mismatch).

You may want to start your `Sub` with this:

```
If Selection Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing is selected!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
ElseIf TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
    MsgBox "Please select a cell!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: You might also run into trouble with `.printObject`. Seems to be a property of `controlFormat`. Try `.controlFormat.printObject` instead.

Comment: @Dschuli `ImageObject` has been declared as a `Picture` OLE Object, not as a `Shape`, so that issue should be sorted.  A good catch for if anyone does try this with a `Shape` though.